# Wildcard SSL and EV SSL

Tags: tls, certificates, sub-domain

Is it possible to mix a Wildcard SSL for subdomains and an EV SSL for the www and non-www domain? I know that an EV SSL can't have a wildcard.

Example:

```
hello.test.com  -> wildcard ssl
hello2.test.com -> wildcard ssl
www.test.com    -> green bar ev ssl
test.com        -> green bar ev ssl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  When the www or root domain are accessed, the users will see the green bar in the browser, since those sites will be returning the EV certificate.   When a user loads a page from another sub-domain, it will be served over HTTPS, but without the green bar, since those sites will be using the wildcard non-EV certificate.

If the resources are mixed, I.E. the page is loaded from a domain using the EV certificate and other resources (javascript, images, etc.) are loaded from sub-domains, the green bar will be shown because it is the certificate for the page that determines the UX, not the certificate used for secondary resources as I've also detailed in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/79363/12).